# Trying to save to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication

Hi am trying to save to MongoDB however the file is always empty I call the
function from a.ejs file with

`<button onclick="Register(usernameRegister.value,passwordRegister.value)">Register</button>`

and then inside my server.js file the
function Register() should send the data off

`function Register(usernameRegister, passwordRegister) {
    var myData = new User({
        username: usernameRegister,
        password: passwordRegister
    });
    myData.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Ran?');
    });`

But nothing at all, I know the
function is running cause I can place an alert inside of it and it will fire but still nothing o.o any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.: )